# Search the Alphanumeric values from column C's each cell in column D's each cell if found mark/highlight in column D or column E

Tags: excel, vba, string, alphanumeric

Search alphanumeric serial numbers from column C's every row in column D, which is having a string in each row and after finding give some mark to that row(eg. highlight with color)

Give some type of highlight to column D where serial number matched with column C. 
Column C has more than 8000 entries and column D has around 2500 entries.

[EXAMPLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LT84W.png)

Comment: Were you planning on showing us the code you are using?

Comment: I didn't used any code for this as someone told me that this is possible only in VBA. Please help if any one having code regarding my query.

Comment: Does it have to match the value in the same row of column C, or any value in the column?

Comment: I want to search each value of column "C" in column "D". If it finds in column "D" then mark/highlight that cell.

Comment: In the text you speak about columns `A` and `B` but the image shows `C` and `D`, in the following I refer to the image. Do you want that the serial nr in `C1` is searched for (1) in all cells in column `D` or (2) only in cell `D1`? If (1) and there are two or more pairs of cells with matching serial numbers, how do you want to mark those?

Comment: I can't see a single row that matches in your example but this can probably be done with conditional formatting

Comment: @Tom Brunberg, sir i want to search C1 in all cells in column D, as you mentioned that "if there are one or more pairs of cells with matching the serial number " kindly add "A","B","C" for those matched cells with serial number eg. "CB47812647 A","CB47812647 B","CB47812647 C" in the column "E" .

Answer (score 2):

Using Conditional Formatting I'm using the following formula

```
=IFERROR(FIND($C1,$D1),-1)>0
```

and formatted it to fill with a colour if `True`

or even better you can use the formula from @Plutian below which will ignore where both cells in columns `C` and `D` are blank

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH($C1,$D1)))>0
```

[image]

I've then applied it to the range I want it to work on

[image]

Giving the following results

[image]

Update after comments:

For column `C` use the following conditional formatting formula

```
=IFNA(MATCH("*"&C1&"*",$D$1:$D$3,0),-1)>0
```

and for column `D` use

```
=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF(D1,"*"&$C$1:$C$3&"*"))>0
```

Giving:

[image]

Comment: To add to this, the formula in this answer will also highlight blank cells if applied to range `$C:$D` instead. The formula `=SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH($C1,$D1)))>0` does not, but gets the same results.

Comment: Thanks @Plutian Have updated my answer to recommend your formula

Comment: Not working as column "C" has around 8000 cells through witch i have to search and column "D" has more than 2500 cells.

Comment: @Tom, Hi it's not working not it selects n highlight  all the cells in column "D". If you want i can upload the xls sheet.